# Angular 2 How i get response data from Post Request

Tags: angular, angular2-services

The Post-Request get the Response from API with the new token, how i can get the token parameter from the Response-Data.

This doesnt working...

> .map { response: Response => { let token = response.json().token }

The Response from post-request with **token** from REST-API

```
{ 
   { "token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0OTc1NDAzNDgsImp0aSI6IjVVNHJLazlONThmOHVaUVZPNkNVNHBYRUR3ZGdQbFE0TWNYU3l6YnFPMzA9IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0Ojg4ODhcL2RiYW5kand0XC8iLCJuYmYiOjE0OTc1NDAzNTgsImV4cCI6MTQ5NzU0NzU1OCwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIzIiwidXNlck5hbWUiOiJtYXJjby5saW5rZSIsImlzQWRtaW4iOmZhbHNlfX0.NOyLSB7N4TtVv9w7dw7mPrL5MUcAVjExycCSG-iJlqHiT3mugh20kq1T2N9RrBXsHO9XsvfEfrJ7k04QOw8hYw"
}
```

}

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http
     .post('http://localhost:8888/dbandjwt/', 
          JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
     .map( (response: Response) => {
            let data = response.json().token;  //how i get the token from response data?
            let token = data.token; 
            if (token) { 
               this.token = token;
               localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));
       })
   }
```

Comment: are you subscribing anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your json generates parse errors, first use

```
.map { response: Response => { let token = response.text()}
```

then extract only this part of the response (you had `{{"token":"etc.."}}` should be `{"token":"etc.."}`

```
{ "token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0OTc1NDAzNDgsImp0aSI6IjVVNHJLazlONThmOHVaUVZPNkNVNHBYRUR3ZGdQbFE0TWNYU3l6YnFPMzA9IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0Ojg4ODhcL2RiYW5kand0XC8iLCJuYmYiOjE0OTc1NDAzNTgsImV4cCI6MTQ5NzU0NzU1OCwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIzIiwidXNlck5hbWUiOiJtYXJjby5saW5rZSIsImlzQWRtaW4iOmZhbHNlfX0.NOyLSB7N4TtVv9w7dw7mPrL5MUcAVjExycCSG-iJlqHiT3mugh20kq1T2N9RrBXsHO9XsvfEfrJ7k04QOw8hYw"
}
```

and then you can cast it to JSON using `JSON.parse(str)` or any method you know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are subscribing it in one of your component.

**In Service**

```
....
.map((response: Response) => response.json())
.catch(......
```

**In Component**

```
.subscribe(
    data => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
......
```

This should solve your problem..